# Tensorflow - outputting predicted value in Multilayer Perceptron Regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression, perceptron

I have looked at all the similar answers to my question and am somehow still not getting it. My model/network is learning, my MSEs are getting smaller, but when I output the predicted values using the input data, it actually performs worse the lower my MSE gets.

I am outputting continuous data in this case, have removed the softmax, and am using the last layer of the network to generate floating point output. Like others here, I started with SciKit and model.predict(X). I appear to be missing something conceptual about how Tensorflow works. I suspect that the variable I'm calling "predicted" below is not what I think it is... That would be the statement predicted = sess.run(neural_network, feed_dict={x: X}).

Here's my code, any help appreciated. I can't supply the data publicly, but I could mock some up if this question is deeper than I think. Thanks!

```
# Import stuff
import tensorflow as tf
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Set up some global processing variables
input_DIM  = 3
output_DIM = 1
Epochs     = 500
Learn_Rate = .17
model_path = "C:\AML\Models\MLPerceptron"

# Define hidden layers and neurons
n_hidden_1 = 50
n_hidden_2 = 50
n_hidden_3 = 50
n_hidden_4 = 2

# ------------------ #
# Load the test file #
# ------------------ #
def read_dataset():
    df = pd.read_csv("C:\AML\data\test.csv")
   # print(len(df.columns))
    X = df[df.columns[0:3]].values
    Y = df[df.columns[3:4]].values

    return (X, Y)



X, Y = read_dataset() ;

#--------------------#
# TensorFlow Section #
#--------------------#


# Create placeholders, variables, tensors
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, input_DIM])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([input_DIM, output_DIM]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([output_DIM]))

# Diagnostic variables
cost_history = np.empty(shape=[1], dtype=float)
mse_history = []
accuracy_history = []
predicted = []


# Define the network structure 
# NOTE: SoftMax activation layer removed to allow floating point output
def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases):

    # Hidden layer with tanh activation
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.tanh(layer_1)

    # Hidden layer with tanh activation
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.tanh(layer_2)

    # Hidden layer with tanh activation
    layer_3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['h3']), biases['b3'])
    layer_3 = tf.nn.tanh(layer_3)

    # Final layer with sigmoid activation
    layer_4 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_3, weights['h4']), biases['b4'])
    layer_4 = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer_4)

    # Output layer with linear activation (softmax REMOVED)
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_4, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer
    #return layer_4

# Define the weights and the biases for each layer

weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([input_DIM, n_hidden_1])),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
    'h3': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_2, n_hidden_3])),
    'h4': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_3, n_hidden_4])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_4, output_DIM]))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_2])),
    'b3': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_3])),
    'b4': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_4])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([output_DIM]))
}

# Define the perceptron network
neural_network = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases)

# Create a placeholder for the expected result during training
expected = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, output_DIM])


# Define TensorFlow session vars
sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()

# Define the loss function as squared difference of net and expected
cost_function = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(expected - neural_network))

# Define training step using gradient descent
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(Learn_Rate).minimize(cost_function)

sess.run(init)

# ---------------------------------- #
# Begin machine learning in earnest! #
# ---------------------------------- #

for i in range(Epochs):   

   # Execute training step 
   sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: X, expected: Y})

   # Munge some diagnostics
   cost = sess.run(cost_function, feed_dict={x: X, expected: Y})
   cost_history = np.append(cost_history, cost)
   predicted = sess.run(neural_network, feed_dict={x: X})
   mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(predicted - Y))
   mse_ = sess.run(mse)
   mse_history.append(mse_)  

   print('epoch : ', i, ' - ', 'cost: ', cost, " - MSE: ", mse_)



print (predicted)
```

Update: I think my problem is understanding what's inside the tensor named "predicted". Below is a dump of the feature matrix X, the Y vector I'm training on, and the predicted output from tf.

Coming from a numpy/SciKit world, I was expecting a single column vector as the output. But that's clearly not what is being generated. I have some questions:

1. Why does't tf simply return the predicted values as a column vector mirroring the input?
2. Where in the predicted tensor is that information located?
3. How does one extract it? I've tried several things but am not having much success in indexing the tensor using the usual numpy methods.

   Feature Matrix

   [[  3.05194408e-04   9.31436261e-09   2.00724503e-06  -7.80543587e-07]
    [  3.05194408e-04   9.31436261e-09   2.00724503e-06  -7.80543587e-07]
    [  3.66233289e-04   1.86287252e-09   1.11772351e-08   4.19146318e-07]
    ..., 
    [  1.13227125e-02  -1.12517500e-06  -1.23229029e-06  -1.43068610e-06]
    [ -2.84441188e-02  -1.21366156e-06  -2.33883657e-06  -3.17060903e-06]
    [ -6.54641986e-02  -1.12983219e-06  -2.34349363e-06  -4.67581049e-06]]

   Target Y vector

   [[ -3.05194408e-05]
    [ -3.05194408e-05]
    [  3.05194408e-04]
    ..., 
    [  9.45797488e-02]
    [  4.90752608e-02]
    [  1.76097173e-02]]
   epoch :  0  -  cost:  0.299485  - MSE:  0.299485
   epoch :  1  -  cost:  0.278928  - MSE:  0.278928
   epoch :  2  -  cost:  0.232972  - MSE:  0.232972
   epoch :  3  -  cost:  0.221542  - MSE:  0.221542
   epoch :  4  -  cost:  0.216305  - MSE:  0.216305
   epoch :  5  -  cost:  0.211555  - MSE:  0.211555
   epoch :  6  -  cost:  0.204823  - MSE:  0.204823
   epoch :  7  -  cost:  0.190776  - MSE:  0.190776
   epoch :  8  -  cost:  0.155517  - MSE:  0.155517
   epoch :  9  -  cost:  0.136089  - MSE:  0.136089

   Predicted

   [[  4.07929212e-01   2.27119313e-06   1.24767032e-02 ...,   1.15948327e-01
       1.12259677e-02   1.41322374e-01]
    [  4.07929212e-01   2.27119313e-06   1.24767032e-02 ...,   1.15948327e-01
       1.12259677e-02   1.41322374e-01]
    [  4.07875597e-01   2.27081409e-06   1.24729313e-02 ...,   1.15964599e-01
       1.12368921e-02   1.41370580e-01]
    ..., 
    [  4.01492357e-01   2.19653884e-06   1.19107403e-02 ...,   1.17981538e-01
       1.31033035e-02   1.47243097e-01]
    [  4.21375126e-01   2.47630169e-06   1.40144946e-02 ...,   1.13659360e-01
       7.23242434e-03   1.27145886e-01]
    [  4.32397932e-01   2.74293211e-06   1.61206387e-02 ...,   1.16918713e-01
       3.85677768e-03   1.13023274e-01]]

Comment: Are you monitoring your MSE from a validation sample of data (i.e. set aside form you training data)?

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding. I'm just passing the training data back through the model and seeing what it does. I realize this could result in overfitting etc., but as a first program, I'm try to keep things as clear as possible. Am I inferencing on the input matrix (X) correctly here? It seems like I'm doing something wrong... I could replace X with other data easily.

Comment: On the training inputs. It's as if the "predicted" output is the reduced "error" rather than the inferenced values. Inferenced values are actually closer to the input when I have a low epochs model (with low neuron counts) and high MSE. It's the opposite of what I anticipated basically.

Comment: `mse_` should equal `sess.run(cost_function, feed_dict={x: X, expected: Y})`, right?  Does it?

Comment: I just tested that - it matches out to 5 decimal places, so yes.

Comment: How do you know your MSEs are getting lower during training?  `sess.run(cost_function, feed_dict={x: X, expected: Y})` should be the same as your `cost` varaible (which I hadn't realized when I wrote last time).

Comment: I'm storing it in MSE_history and plotting with mathplotlib. At epoch 1 I'm typically at something like .24356, by epoch 100 10^-5 or better.

Comment: Update: cost variable matches MSE as well.

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding where the discrepancy is then.  You verified `mse_ == cost` and you're saying that `mse_history` is minimizing as expected.  Which variable is performing worse?

Comment: Hey, I got pulled away... I'm going to gin up a test data set and test the predictions on that, then I'll share something more concrete. Thanks so much for your help - I very much appreciate it. I'm also getting a message from S.O. to avoid extended discussions so I'll move this to PM...